# Having SQL Data Table Permanently on VB.NET Form and not directly editable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm using this code:

```
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    BindGrid()
End Sub
Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim constring As String = "server=classified;database=classified"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Salespeople", con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Is there a way to get the table on the form such that the table cannot be edited directly? I only want the stuff edited through the textboxes!

Comment: A [DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) is not a visual object, so you need to explain better. A [DataGirdView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx) however will display db data in table form.

Comment: As an aside there are a number of other issues there.  For instance your DataAdapter cannot fill the DataSet/DataTable is the connection is closed.

Comment: @Plutonix As an update: The question has changed a bit, or more than a bit.

Comment: I would not use select * either. You should only select the columns you need.

Comment: In this scenario, I do want the contents of the tables to be seeable to the user. I just don't want the user to be able to edit the tables directly (if that makes any sense realistically). I only want the tables to be edited through the textboxes I have included on my form.

Comment: Entering data into a DGV you will have the same amount of control as using textboxes etc.  The DGV has oodles of events to allow you to validate data before actually updating the underlying DataTable

Comment: @CorbinRessl The term you're looking for is [Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) You can easily create a binding between a data-table (often using a [BindingSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and a control, either programmatically or by using the IDE. For a read-only binding, make sure the `DataSourceUpdateMode` is set to `Never`.